# Data Base with anonymous users

Tags: php, android, mysql

I need an online Data Base with anonymous connection that works with Android. I need my app to connect anonymously to a Data Base to retrieve, and send data, I have been searching for tutorials but as far as I've seen the most easy way is using  PHP + MySql (I have never used webservices but Im learning) but I haven't seen MySql connection without user login, so does MySql allow anyonymous users connect to my Data Base? And how would it be?

Comment: You never have a case where each user connects, you create a single generic user that has certain permissions. This generic user is used by the PHP script.

Comment: +1 for what Jay said.  You are overthinking this.  When you use the search box here on Stack Overflow, or on any website,  you anonymously sending a query and retrieving data. But you don't have direct access to the database.

Comment: Though I cant post without login, I need the user to insert information into the database, is it possible with anonymous connection?

Comment: Yes of course it is.   The simplest implementation of what you are saying is a typical html form.  When a site user enters info in the form it is processed and stored in the database.   You might want to read up on $POST and $GET requests.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to look into is using a REST API implementation to handle this for you.  REST uses HTTP to handle requests and responses, and there are lots of options available to you in any programming language your comfortable in.

You mention PHP, so you might look at Slim http://www.slimframework.com/

But there are REST APIs designed specifically for Android like https://github.com/manavo/Android-RESTapi.

Do your research to find one that will best fit your use case.  Look on line for tutorials for **Android REST or RESTful to MySQL** and you will turn up a bunch of info.

You can also look at frameworks like Laravel or Codeiginiter, but they may be overkill for what you want.

Often in PHP you will see something like this in code

```
class The_data { 
     function getData($var1,$var2,$var3) {
       // Do something with the code here....
      }
```

This can translate into https://example.com/the_data/getData/name/something/something_else

So you can pass data first to the Class, then to the Method or function, then to any number of parameters like the $vars in my example.

But if any of the data is sensitive you must do it securely not over http.  Also you need to be sure all the data is sanitized to prevent SQL injection.